# Difference between 'void *' and 'void * (*function)(void *)' initialization, casting, and function pointer calls?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, structure

More specifically, how do these 3 pointers work in the symbol table and compiler?

My understanding is:

`void * object` is a pointer to an object or function with an unspecified type which basically requires casting of the object to interpret correctly such as `(int)object`.

Can casting be done by member/object type as long as the compiler has a valid declaration of type info for that object including storage qualifiers and specifiers in the symbol table?

For example:

```
void * object;
struct Structure {int member;} Structure;
printf("Object is: %d\n", (Structure->member)(*object));
```

or in the case of the function:

```
void * (* function)(void *);
```

my understanding is that the object names a pointer to a function accepting a pointer to an unknown object or function pointer which returns a pointer to an unknown object or function pointer. Function calling/dereferencing is unclear. Supposedly assignment to a void * object which initializes the declaration of the object is supposed to assume the type it is initialized from.

What is the difference between these function pointer calls?

```
    struct Structure {void *member;} Structure;
    Structure.member = &main();
    
   /*This assignment, based on my understanding, to Structure.member from main() is supposed to 
    *initialize ember to the type of main() which is assigned automatically or via memcpy()*/

    Structure.member(arg); 
    /*or:*/ 
    Structure.(*(member(arg))); 
    /*or:*/ 
    Structure.(*member(arg)));
```

This format then appears to be:

```
(cast_type) (return_object_type_qualifiers_specifiers)(object_name)(object_parameters);
```

How does this grouping work?

Comment: You seem to have several questions mixed together here, and it might help to kind of pick them apart.  Here's a couple comments that might help you clarify.

Comment: (1) A cast requires a type name, not an expression, so `(Structure->member)(*object))` isn't a cast.  It would be parsed as a function call, and fail because `(Structure->member)` is of type `int` and not a pointer to function.  Some compilers have extensions to let you recover an expression's type, e.g. [GCC's `typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), with which you could write `(typeof(Structure->member))(*object)` to cast to `int`.  But standard C doesn't provide anything like that.

Comment: (2) `Structure.member = &main();`:  Putting parentheses after a function name always causes it to be called.  If you just want to take the address of the function to call it later, write `... = &main;` or just `... = main;`.

Comment: Thank you for the response; I didn't know about the GCC extension nor the rules of parenthesis being explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `void *` contains no information about the the type of the object it points to.  It's up to the programmer to keep track of it and convert it back to the proper pointer type.

In this example:

```
struct Structure {void *member;} Structure;
Structure.member = &func;
```

It's not valid to treat `Structure.member` as a function because that's not its type.  It would need to be cast back to the proper function pointer type before it could be called.  So if `func` is defined as `void func(void)`, you would need to do this:

```
((void (*)(void))Structure.member)();
```

Also, it's not strictly allowed to convert a function pointer to an object pointer, and a `void *` is an object pointer, however most implementation you're likely to use will still support it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same about casting however I discovered the compiler I am using supported the generic void * reference for objects and functions.